# Edit link on div mouseover

Tags: javascript

On facebook for example - when you put your mouseover a news item, a remove button appears. How can I go about making this happen?

Thanks,
Elliot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Modern Browsers

In modern browsers, you can leverage the `:hover` pseudo class in our selector. As an example, consider the following markup:

```html
<div class="item">
  <p>This is a long string of text</p>
  <div class="adminControls">
    <a href="#" title="Delete">Delete Item</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

By default, we would want the `.adminControls` to be hidden. They should, however, become visible once the user has hovered the `.item` element:

```css
.item .adminControls {
    display: none;
}

.item:hover .adminControls {
    display: block;
}
```

#### JavaScript and jQuery

If you're using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), you can accomplish this rather easily using the $.hover() method. If you're using Prototype, you can get the [protoHover plugin](http://code.google.com/p/protohover/) to achieve the same result, or view [this blog post](http://www.zurielbarron.com/2009/01/30/jquery-hover-with-prototype/).

```js
$("div.item").hover(
  function () { $(this).find(".adminControls").show(); }, 
  function () { $(this).find(".adminControls").hide(); }
);
```

That would accomplish the show/hide effect for the following:

```html
<div class="item">
  <p>This is a long string of text</p>
  <div class="adminControls">
    <a href="#" title="Delete">Delete Item</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <p>This is a long string of text</p>
  <div class="adminControls">
    <a href="#" title="Delete">Delete Item</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <p>This is a long string of text</p>
  <div class="adminControls">
    <a href="#" title="Delete">Delete Item</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine with just jQuery, as the answer says.

Comment: Also make sure that .adminControls is hidden to start with.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan!

I'd like to use this in rails - which includes the prototype library - will this code work with prototype as justin said?

Comment: @Elliot, you can do this with Prototype too - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support IE6, you can use the :hover pseudoclass like so:

CSS:

```
.link { display: none; }
.item:hover > .link { display: inline; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
  <a href="#" class="link">Remove</a>
  Lorem Ipsum...
</div>
```

Comment: I moved the `href` after the `Lorem Ipsum...` text and this achieved the effect I was after. I wanted the Remove (in my case edit) to appear AFTER the text instead of before.

Answer (score 0):

Position the link as you'd like it to appear on hover, then hide it with JavaScript and use the `onmouseover` event to show it. (i.e., it's `display: none;` and then turns to `display: block;` when the `onmouseover` event is triggered).

Something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('mylink').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('mydiv').onmouseover = function(){
        document.getElementById('mylink').style.display = 'block';  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a Javascript function that manipulates the DOM and you need to associate the OnMouseOver attribute of your HTML element with that function. For example, on my home page a picture of my face changes every time the mouse rolls over it. The Javascript function is defined in the HTML page itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
faceCnt = 7;
var faces = new Array( faceCnt ); 
var faceDates = new Array( "1982", "1986", "1991", "1999", "2004", "2006", "2009" );
var faceIdx = 7; /* So that first change is to earliest one. */
for( var idx = 0 ; idx < faceCnt ; idx++ )
  (faces[idx] = new Image(150, 116)).src = "david/david" + (idx + 1) + ".jpg";

function nextFace( ref )
{
  faceIdx = faceIdx >= faceCnt - 1 ? 0 : faceIdx + 1;
  ref.src = faces[ faceIdx ].src;
  ref.title = "David-" + faceDates[ faceIdx ];
}
//-->
</script>

<img id="myface" src="david/david7.jpg" alt="david" title="David-2009" 
 width="150" height="116" 
 style="margin: 0 0 5px 15px; /* -10px -5px 10px 10px; */
  padding: 0;
   border: solid black;
   border-width: 1px;
   float: right;" 
  onMouseOver="nextFace( this )"
  onClick="nextFace( this )" >
```